# SoapUI authentication vs C#

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, soapui, basic-authentication

I have a web service that works fine in SoapUI using the following credentials:

```
Authentication: Basic
Username: testUser
Password: testPassword
Domain: IPaddress
```

When I try to us it in my C# application using this code

```
soapWS.Service soapWS = new soapWS.Service();
soapWS.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("testUser", "testPassword", "IPaddress");
```

I get the following error

> Exception startSession: FailedLoginException for user IPaddress\testUser; nested exception is:

I did some more research on SoapUI and the domain in SoapUI is

```
Domain : The domain to use if the request requires NTLM authentication)
```

I tried

```
soapWS.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("testUser@IPaddress", "testPassword");
```

Which did not work either.

Comment: Is there really no detail for the nested exception, or have you omitted the vital part of the message?

Comment: Actually there is nothing after is:

Answer (score 0):

Last parameter of NetworkCredential constructor should be domain name and IPaddress.
Following  line

```
soapWS.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("testUser", "testPassword", "IPaddress");
```

should be

```
soapWS.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("testUser", "testPassword", "your domain name");
```

Comment: ok  I see the issue this constructor is authentication to an actual Windows Domain thus the Domain\user error. Is there a object other than NetworkCredential that works for basic Webservice authorization?

Comment: Try this soapWS.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("testUser", "testPassword")

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was drop the "IPaddress" in my Object.

```
soapWS.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("testUser", "testPassword");
```